Getting an error while running my web scraping python script
I have a python script that downloads images from a website based on values taken from an Excel workbook. However, I keep getting this error:

INFO: Created TensorFlow Lite XNNPACK delegate for CPU.
WARNING: Attempting to use a delegate that only supports static-sized tensors with a graph that has dynamic-sized tensors (tensor#141 is a dynamic-sized tensor).

It never used to appear, the code would just run and finish executing. But after the appearance of this error, the program just ends abruptly.
I have pasted my code below.
Idk for what reason, but it doesn't delete the rows from the Excel workbook as well. Any idea why?
import os
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

def onescript(driver):
    book = load_workbook('trial.xlsx')
    sheet1 = book.active
    print(driver.title)
    driver.get("https://www.jaquar.com/en/") #Open the web page
    
    for i in range(1,4):
        prod_id = sheet1.cell(row=i+1, column=2).value

        #Click add Product :
        search_product = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "small-searchterms"))
        )
        search_product.clear()
        search_product.send_keys(prod_id)
        search_product.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
        book.save('trial.xlsx')

        if driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "button-2"):
            # Click add Image :
            click_details = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "button-2"))
            )
            click_details.click()

            # Download image - Set download directory if needed( same as the one to upload )
            download_image = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "download-image"))
            )
            download_image.click()

            product_found = True

        if not product_found:
            print("No product found")
            sheet1.delete_rows(i, 1)  # Delete the row where the product was not found
            book.save('updated_trial.xlsx')
        else:
            # Reset the index if a row was deleted
            pass
    book.save('trial.xlsx')       
        
absolute_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
relative_path1 = "drivers\\chromedriver-win64\\chromedriver.exe"
full_path_cdriver = os.path.join(absolute_path, relative_path1)
relative_path2 = "drivers\\chrome-win64\\chrome.exe"
full_path_chrome = os.path.join(absolute_path, relative_path2)

#Upload your user-data folder so that the testing browser can know your cookies
options = Options()
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:/Users/xyzs/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome for Testing/User Data")
options.binary_location = full_path_chrome
service = Service(executable_path=full_path_cdriver)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=service)

onescript(driver)

Any help is appreciated.

What's the contents and format of the xlsx? Add that to your question. We need some sample prod_ids to be able to walk through your script.

That "error" is just an INFO message and won't stop the execution of your script. What's the actual error message you are getting when the script fails/stops?

the prod_is is basically 1,2,3. dummy data

I'm not getting any error apart from this. i do, sometimes, get a failed handshake message

This line if not product_found: could be a problem in your code. product_found is only defined if the first criteria is True, so if it isn't and that line is evaluated the code will error. Why save 'updated_trial.xlsx' every time you delete a line. There is no reason to do this until the loop ends at least. Why save 'trial.xlsx' if you are saving 'updated_trial.xlsx'. At least you are saving it after the loop completes. Looks like you are reading from row i+1 and deleting row i, so seems you are deleting a different product if not found.

"the prod_is is basically 1,2,3. dummy data" would show up the first listed issue in the above comment. If we don't know what to search for, chances of having a search that makes if driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "button-2"): TRUE are less, resulting in the undefined if not product_found: line being run and the code crashing.

The main problem is that the element that you found by (By.CLASS_NAME, "button-2") no longer exists. Because you check for it's existence, most of your code doesn't run. I've updated the code to work based on the current site and the info you provided.
This code will search for an ID, open the first found product, and download it's image. I didn't test any of the Excel related code.
import os
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

def onescript(driver):
    book = load_workbook('trial.xlsx')
    sheet1 = book.active
    driver.get("https://www.jaquar.com/en/")
    driver.maximize_window()
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

    # close site popup
    try:
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "btn_redirect_close"))).click()
    except:
        # ignore if not there
        pass

    for i in range(1,4):
        prod_id = sheet1.cell(row=i+1, column=2).value

        # search for product
        wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "small-searchterms"))).send_keys(f"{prod_id}\n")

        try:
            # click first product
            wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.product-item a[title]"))).click()
            # download image
            wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "download-image"))).click()

        except:
            print("No product found")
            sheet1.delete_rows(i, 1)  # delete the row where the product was not found
            book.save('updated_trial.xlsx')
        
absolute_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
relative_path1 = "drivers\\chromedriver-win64\\chromedriver.exe"
full_path_cdriver = os.path.join(absolute_path, relative_path1)
relative_path2 = "drivers\\chrome-win64\\chrome.exe"
full_path_chrome = os.path.join(absolute_path, relative_path2)

# upload your user-data folder so that the testing browser can know your cookies
options = Options()
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:/Users/xyzs/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome for Testing/User Data")
options.binary_location = full_path_chrome
service = Service(executable_path=full_path_cdriver)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=service)

onescript(driver)

